# Manipulation of (rather) simple linear algebra expression.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the following expression: $$(x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu) + (\mu-\mu_0)^T S^{-1} (\mu-\mu_0),$$ where $x, \mu, \mu_0$ are vectors and $\Sigma, S$ are invertible square matrices.

**Expand the expression so that there are only quadratic terms.** How do I do this?

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Formally expand this by "FOILing" each product:
$$
(x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu) + (\mu-\mu_0)^T S^{-1} (\mu-\mu_0) = \\
x^T \Sigma^{-1} x -
\mu^T \Sigma^{-1} x -
x^T \Sigma^{-1} \mu + 
\mu^T \Sigma^{-1} \mu + \\
\mu^T S^{-1} \mu - 
\mu_0^T S^{-1} \mu -
\mu^T S^{-1} \mu_0 +
\mu_0^T S^{-1} \mu_0
$$

Comment: But where are the quadratic terms?

Comment: What is your definition of a quadratic term?  I expanded because the question said "expand"; this is the most you can expand it.  The way I see it, the original form already has quadratic terms.